# Can someone explain why im getting mpair contract violation

Tags: racket

Define a SCHEME procedure, named (tree-sort l), which takes a list of numbers and outputs the same
list, but in sorted order. Your procedure should sort the list by
(a) inserting the numbers into a binary search tree and, then,
(b) extracting from the binary search tree a list of the elements in sorted order.
To get started, write a procedure called (insert-list L T) which takes a list of numbers L and a binary
search tree T, and returns the tree that results by inserting all numbers from L into T. (Place the argument
L first, so a call to your function should have the form (insert-list L T), where L is a list and T is a
(perhaps empty) binary search tree.)
Then write a function called sort-extract which takes a binary search tree and outputs the elements of
the tree in sorted order. (We did this in class!)
Finally, put these two functions together to achieve (tree-sort l). (Note, all three of these functions
will be graded, so your solutions must consist of three top-level functions, insert-list, sort-extract,
and tree-sort.)

```
(define (insert-list insert-elements T)
      (if (null? insert-elements)
          T
          (insert-list (cdr insert-elements)
                       (insert-list (car insert-elements) T))))

(insert-list (list 12) (list 15 (list) (list)))
```

mcdr: contract violation
expected: mpair?
given: 12

Comment: You're supposed to implement another function that inserts just one element, and then use that in `insert-list`.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting contract violations because you are calling `insert-list` with the `car` which is 12. Since it is not `null?` you'll try to do `car` and `cdr` of it. What is the `cdr` of 12?

Also for me it seems strange that you are not calling the procedure to add an element to a tree from `insert-list`. I can't think of any good reason to combine those two procedures in one.

If you had a procedure that takes a value and a tree and returns a tree with that value added you can do this:

```
(define (insert-list lst tree)
  (foldl insert tree lst))
```

Eg.

```
(insert-list '(5 2 4) '()) ; ==>
(insert 4 (insert 2 (insert 5 '())))
```